# Get id of image after click on p element in drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<table class="canToggle">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="messagepop pop">
                <p class="selection">moss</p>
                <p class="selection">gray</p>
                <p class="close">Cancel</p>
            </div>
            <img src="images/gray.jpg" class="wide high image" id="x1y1" />
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
<table>
```

When I click one of the `p`s, I need to get the id of the `img` so that I can change the `img src`. I have this JQuery:

```
var $selection = $(this).text();
$selection = "images/" + $selection + ".jpg";
// I need to populate the value of nextImgID for the next line
$(nextImgID).attr('src', $selection);
```

I can't figure out how to traverse this. I've looked at the api and some questions here, but things depend on sibling relationships. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up to `td` then find image

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
$(this).closest('td').find('img').attr('src', $selection);
```

You can also use

```
$(this).closest('div').next('img').attr('src', $selection);
```

Comment: WOW That did it! Thank you! I was going all around this and never got it right.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).on("click","selection",function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent(); // messagepopup div
    var imgId = parent.next("img:first").attr("id");
});
```

You can get the img element by `parent.next("img:first")`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
var image = $(this).parents('td').find('img').attr('src', 'url');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You can first search for parent 'td' and then you can find image id.

```
$('p').click(function(){
var imageid =$(this).parents('td').find('img').attr('id');
//in image id you will get your image's id
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$("p").click(function() {
  alert($(this).parent().siblings().attr("id"));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="canToggle">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="messagepop pop">
        <p class="selection">moss</p>
        <p class="selection">gray</p>
        <p class="close">Cancel</p>
      </div>
      <img src="images/gray.jpg" class="wide high image" id="x1y1" />
    </td>

  </tr>
  <table>
```